# How do I redirect after a few seconds from JSP page to Servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have been searching a lot for the answer but can't seem to find one.

I have a message to display to a user on a JSP page and want to redirect it to a servlet using the following URL :
/BenchmarkWeb/Servlet?action=initiate

Can you guys help on what statement or method I would need to use to redirect this say, 10 seconds after it has been loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by using meta redirect :

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=http://yournewurl">
```

Comment: @back2basics Don't forget to mark answer that works for you as accepted (either on your other questions if it is the case!). You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).